# Adding in List<string> overwrites previous value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, webforms

I have a very simple C# program to write (for an ASP.Net web application) that takes input from an textbox, stores it in a list and then displays it in a listbox. This is my code:

```
public partial class Form: System.Web.UI.Page
{
        List<string> students = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox.DataSource = students;
        }

        protected void Display_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (this.students.Count != 0)
           {
                for (int x = 0; x < students.Count; x++)
                {
                    ListBox.Items.Add((x + 1).ToString() + ". " + students[x]);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void AddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            if(tbxStudentInput.Text != "")
            {
                students.Add(tbxStudentInput.Text);
                tbxStudentInput.Text = "";
            }
       }
}
```

Every time I add to my list however, it overwrites the previous value. And when I try to display the stored values in the listbox, it says count is 0. Would you instruct me as to what I am doing wrong that is not storing the values in the list correctly. Thanks

Comment: Every time the page loads, your list is empty. HTTP is state-less, if you want to save user-states, you have to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime, you hit the form it creates new instance of students as HTTP is stateless.

Try moving instantiation of students i.e. List students = new List(); in a static contructor

i.e.

```
static Page()
    {
      students = new List<string>();
    }
```

Ideal way is to fetch this from database though.